# Socket.io - dragging DIV by multiple users not working

Tags: html, jquery, socket.io

I'm trying to use this on my webpage. But when I'm opening the webpage in two different webbrowsers, and when I drag the div, it doesn't update on both, just the one i'm dragging in. Below is the code I'm using. Why is this not working?

Below is index.html in my http://mywebsite.com/myProject/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var socket = io("http://mywebsite.com/myProject/");
      socket.on('update_position', function (data) {
        var x = data.x;
        var y = data.y;
        // jquery code to move div here
        $("#left").val(x);
        $("#top").val(y);
        $("#mydiv").css({
          left: x + "px",
          top: y + "px"
        });
      });

      $("#mydiv").draggable({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
          var coord = $(this).position();
          $("#left").val(coord.left);
          $("#top").val(coord.top);
          socket.emit('receive_position', {
            x: coord.left,
            y: coord.top
          });
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
  <style> 
    .dstyle
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px; height: 50px;
        background: #ffb; padding: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #999;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  X: <input type="text" id="left"/>
  Y: <input type="text" id="top"/>

  <div id="mydiv" class="dstyle">drag me</div>
</body>
```

And here is the server.js below

```js
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(3000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

var lastPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // whatever default data

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('update_position', lastPosition);
  socket.on('receive_position', function (data) {
     lastPosition = data;
     socket.broadcast.emit('update_position', data); // send `data` to all other clients
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! The problem was that my webhosting did not support Node JS, so now I am using glitch.com which has free hosting supporting Node JS